# How do I use predict command in R to validate my training model decision tree

Tags: r, decision-tree, predict

I've created a decision tree training model using ctree function from the "party" library to help teachers decide which students to follow up. Now I want to apply this training model to my test set in order to predict whether a teacher should "(1) intervene", "(2) monitor student progress" or "(3) take no action" based on how many problems students have answered before, the percentage of those problems they got correct, and how many hints they required.

```
library(party)

D1 <- read.csv(training data with 378 observations and 4 variables: 
               prior_prob_count, prior_percent_correct, hints_count, score)
```

#### HW1. Create a categorical outcome variable based on student score to advise the teacher using an "ifelse" statement:

`D1$advice <- ifelse(D1$score < 0.5, "1", ifelse(D1$score < 0.6, "2", "3"))`

If student's score is less than 0.5, teacher should intervene (1). Else, if student's score is less than 0.6, teacher should monitor student progress (2). Else, if student's score is above 0.6, teacher should take no action (3).

#### HW2. Build a decision tree that predicts "advice":

```
D1$advice <- as.factor(D1$advice) 
score_ctree <- ctree(advice ~ prior_prob_count + prior_percent_correct + hints, data=D1)
plot(score_ctree)  # see image for visualization
```

[plot(score_ctree)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttvki.png)

#### HW3. Upload new test data and generate predicted advice using the predict() command for new students based on tree generated from old students

```
D2 <- read.csv(test data with 200 observations and 4 variables: 
               prior_prob_count, prior_percent_correct, hints_count, score)
D2$prediction <- predict(object = D2, model = score_ctree)
```

Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "data.frame"

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameters of `predict` are wrong. I don't have `party` package installed, but looking at the other `predict` functions it should be:

```
D2$prediction <- predict(newdata = D2, object = score_ctree)
```